# Angular Validate date in reactive forms

Tags: typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to validate the Date format using reactive forms
and display the error message if the format does not match (MM/DD/YYYY)

The valid date formats are:

```
6/30/2020 (MM/DD/YYYY)
12/30/2020  (MM/DD/YYYY)
```

Here is what I have done:

Component:

```
initForm() {    
    this.filterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        valueDate: [this.transactionFilter.valueDate,Validators.pattern(/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[0-9]{4}$/)]
    }, { validators: this.validateFormControls });
}

validateFormControls(control: AbstractController){
    // Some other validations here
}
```

Template

```
<form [formGroup]="filterForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
    <div class="col">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Value Date</mat-label>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="txtValueDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" formControlName="valueDate">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="txtValueDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #txtValueDate></mat-datepicker>
            <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="filterForm.controls['valueDate'].hasError()">Invalid date Format</mat-error> -->
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <button  mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!filterForm.valid">submit</button>  
</form>
```

The submit button is always disabled when I input the date (manually/datepicker). Is there a better way for date validations in reactive forms?

Answer (score 1):

the default date picker format are yyyy-MM-dd so you should do this:

Component

```
export class DateickerComponent {

  public dateForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {

    var today: string | null = new DatePipe("en-US").transform(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd");

    this.dateForm = new FormGroup({
      date: new FormControl(today, Validators.required)
    });
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="dateForm" novalidate>
    <input type="date" formControlName="date">
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you have matches the DD/MM/YYYY date pattern, used in places like Australia and UK.

For the American format that you said MM/DD/YYYY you will need to swap the first two groups to make it

```
(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/[0-9]{4}
```

That will be sufficient to validate the format.  However it will not catch things like putting February 30th etc.
For those kinds of validations, I'd advise the use of a custom validator. I've pasted a rough one below.  It still
doesn't handle February and leap years, and restricts the years actually, but will get you most of the way.

```
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
export function dateValidator(control: FormControl) {
if (!control.value) {
  return { 'datecheck' : true };
}

let curval:string = control.value;
let pieces: string[] = curval.split("/");

if (!pieces || pieces.length != 3) {
  return { 'datecheck' : true };
}

let month:number = +pieces[1];
if (month > 12 || month < 1) {
  return { 'datecheck' : true };
}

let day:number = +pieces[0];
if (day < 1) {
  return { 'datecheck' : true };
}
switch (month) {
  case 9:
  case 4:
  case 6:
  case 11:
    if (day > 30) {
      return { 'datecheck' : true };
    }
    break;
  case 1:
  case 3:
  case 5:
  case 7:
  case 8:
  case 9:
  case 10:
  case 12:
    if (day > 31) {
      return { 'datecheck' : true };
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    if (day > 29) {
      return { 'datecheck' : true };
    }
    break;
}

let year:number = +pieces[2];
if (year > 2100 || year < 1970) {
  return { 'datecheck' : true };
}

let curdate : Date = new Date(+pieces[2], month, day);

if (!isNaN(curdate.getTime())) {  // this is supposed to tell if curdate is valid
  return null;
}

return { 'datecheck' : true };
```

}